# Spring Boot: Change property placeholder signifier

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin

What is the easiest way to change the prefix and suffix for the property placeholder in Spring Boot?

The default is `@Value("${some.property}")`, however this looks ugly in Kotlin, since it needs to be escaped - ${something} is a language feature in Kotlin for String templates.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're not going to be able to do that, as that's defined in SpEL (inherited from general EL). Does Kotlin not have an equivalent to Groovy's single-quote "don't interpolate" string?

Comment: You could always, of course, use `@ConfigurationProperties`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is possible to customize the prefix used by declaring the following beans in your configuration:

```
@Bean
fun propertyConfigurer() = PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer().apply {
    setPlaceholderPrefix("%{")
}
```

if you have any existing code (like Spring Boot actuators or `@LocalServerPort`) that is using the `${...}` syntax, you should declare:

```
@Bean
fun kotlinPropertyConfigurer() = PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer().apply {
    setPlaceholderPrefix("%{")
    setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true)
}

@Bean
fun defaultPropertyConfigurer() = PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer()
```

Escaping the dollar like in `@Value("\${some.property}")` is another possible option that require no `@Bean` declaration.

For Spring Boot tests configured with `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)` you can use `@LocalServerPort` instead of `@Value("\${local.server.port}")`.

[`@ConfigurationProperties`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties) would be a better alternative, especially with Kotlin data classes, but currently you have to use Kotlin classes with nullable `var` properties since only getter/setter are supported. You can vote for [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8762) or comment to show your interest in getting that supported in Spring Boot 2.x.

Comment: Is it possible to use @ConfigurationProperties with Kotlin data classes, or it has to be a regular open class?

Comment: The problem is constructor injection. If you try to create properties in constructor, Spring searches for beans instead of config properties. @Sébastien Deleuze is there a way to disable bean injection for ConfigurationProperties classes?

Comment: The is not supported in Spring Boot 1.x, we are discussing supporting that in Spring Boot 2.x here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8762.

Answer (score 2):

They have a new feature using java classes annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties`. This looks nice in Kotlin and is refactoring save. You should give it a try:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties

Comment: I think that [this link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties) is a better entry point for the feature. Maybe you can edit your answer with that?

Comment: With your help I found a solution that I'm happy with (see below). Thank you.

Comment: Cool. It seems you had a lot of thinks to do to make it run. I'm okay if you put the "tick" to your answer. I upvoted it already

Comment: Accepted new answer, which specifically addresses the problem, but thanks again for you help - am proceeding with @ConfigurationProperties

Answer (score 2):

Using advice from answer provided by dox, I ended up going with something like:

```
public interface TokenAuthenticationConfig {

public fun apiKey() : String

}

@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "service.api")
public open class TokenAuthenticationConfigImpl : TokenAuthenticationConfig
{
    public var apiKey : String

    constructor() {
        this.apiKey = ""
    }

    override fun apiKey(): String
    {
        return this.apiKey
    }
}
```

In Spring `@ConfigurationProperties` objects are required to follow the Java Beans pattern and be, therefore, mutable. To me configuration seems as though it should be generally static throughout app life-cycle, and so rather than add the complexity of reasoning about state, injected the immutable interface instead.